# How to prevent term URL in webform email template (Webform References Module)?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, webforms, emails

I've configured a webform to send a custom email after submit. One of the fields in the webform is a taxonomy select (via the [Webform References](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_references) module). So the value in the email template looks something like this:

```
[submission:values:vocabname]
```

When the email gets sent, the selected taxonomy term gets printed out along with a reference to its URL listed at the bottom... like this:

```
Term Name [1]
```

And then at the bottom of the email is the URL:

```
[1] http://www.example.com/vocab-name/term-name
```

How do I prevent the URL from being included automatically in the email? I just want term name alone.

Answer (score 1):

When returning field value [Webform References](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_references) Module, add link to field output using theme function (theme_webform_display_term_reference_field()), which you can override in your theme's template.php and then clear Site Cache. Check sample code below, which you can write in your theme's template.php:

```
/**
 * Format the output of data for this component.
 */
function [THEME_NAME]_webform_display_term_reference_field($variables) {
  $values = (array) $variables['element']['#value'];
  $items = array();
  foreach (array_filter($values) as $value) {
    $tid = check_plain($value);
    if ($tid) {
      // Do not pass 2nd argument, keep it default i.e. FALSE.
      $items[] = _webform_references_get_term_name($tid);
    }
  }
  $output = count($items) > 1 ? theme('item_list', array('items' => $items)) : (isset($items[0]) ? $items[0] : '');
  return $output;
}
```

**NOTE : This will also remove the Term field link on view submission page.**